# ffmpeg works but gstreamer does not work for rtsp camera

Tags: ffmpeg, gstreamer, nvidia-jetson

I'm using Nvidia Jetson Tx2 device.

With the following command, I can connect and capture an image with ffmpeg.

```
$/usr/bin/ffmpeg -y -frames 1 snapshot.png -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.10.131/1/profile
```

```html
ffmpeg version 3.4.8-0ubuntu0.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.2 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.1 : mono
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.10.131/1/profile':
  Metadata:
    title           : SDP Descrption
    comment         : SDP Description
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuvj420p(pc, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080, 25 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_alaw, 8000 Hz, mono, s16, 64 kb/s
    Stream #0:2: Data: none
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> png (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[swscaler @ 0x55a8f70c70] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x55a8f70c70] No accelerated colorspace conversion found from yuv420p to rgb24.
Output #0, image2, to 'snapshot.png':
  Metadata:
    title           : SDP Descrption
    comment         : SDP Description
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgb24, 1920x1080, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.107.100 png
frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:00.03 bitrate=N/A dup=1 drop=1 speed=0.066x    
video:1982kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
```

But with gstreamer, (I'm using version 1.14.5) I am not able to access the rtsp feed.

```
$gst-launch-1.0 uridecodebin uri=rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.10.131/1/profile ! fakesink
```

```html
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Progress: (open) Opening Stream
Progress: (connect) Connecting to rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.10.131/1/profile
Progress: (open) Retrieving server options
Progress: (open) Retrieving media info
Progress: (request) SETUP stream 0
Progress: (request) SETUP stream 1
Progress: (request) SETUP stream 2
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstRTSPSrc:source: Could not read from resource.
Additional debug info:
gstrtspsrc.c(5917): gst_rtsp_src_receive_response (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstRTSPSrc:source:
Could not receive message. (Timeout while waiting for server response)
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Setting pipeline to READY ...
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

I have also removed gstreamer-ugly pkg but it still does not work!

ref : https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/rtsp-gstreamer-simple-recieve-and-store-in-file/157535/12

Let me know if you can help me! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this by the help of Gstreamer forum.

The problem was that ffmpeg is using tcp when gstreamer is using udp and tcp, and I believe in stream 2, udp is failing. The trick was to put a t to specify tcp

```
$gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtspt://admin:admin@192.168.10.131/1/profile ! fakesink
```

Also, you can see the debug lines by gst_debug

```
$gst-launch-1.0 --gst-debug=rtspsrc:5 uridecodebin uri=rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.10.131/1/profile ! fakesink
```

This is the link.
http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/Ffmpeg-works-but-gstreamer-does-not-work-for-rtsp-camera-tt4696330.html

Also, there is no answer but may helpful in nvidia dev forum
https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/ffmpeg-works-but-gstreamer-does-not-work-for-rtsp-camera/165193/5